# Pycharm default interpreter

Tags: python, pycharm, interpreter

Every single time I open Pycharm I get the "no Pyhon interpreter configured for the project", so I go to Settings -> Interpreter and choose it from the list. But as soon as I close Pycharm and open it again next time, I receive the same message. I went crazy on trying to google for the answer, is there anyway to solve this? I've had Pycharm for a long time and never had this kind of an issue. Fresh install on win 8.1.

Comment: Am using win 8.1

Comment: Where your project is stored? If it is located in the cloud (eg box.com) every time Pycharm re-syncs the project it resets the default interpreter.

Comment: No, I'm running it from local storage.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the default interpreter for PyCharm,   For that, go to :

> `File` > `Preferences for New Projects` > `Project Interpreter`

[image]

Comment: This does not answer the question. He wants to set a default interpreter for that specific project. That should be possible and it should be remembered. However, do to a bug for some of us it is not remembered. (I have the same at the moment.)